# Biblical ‘Noah’ & cinematic ‘Noah’

Tags: history, mabul, performance-entertainment, noach-noah-the-man, popular-culture

How accurate -or not- is the film ‘[Noah](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noah_(2014_film))’ according to the Jewish traditional version of the events and subjects? (I haven’t seen the film so I can’t offer any analyses.)

I’d kindly request that any evaluations be backed up with facts (and/or citations); e.g. “The film gives the impression that the generation’s sin was that the people would eat their steaks with ketchup, while * *insert source* * says it was because of X.”

Comment: Eating a steak with ketchup was actually a sin back then

Comment: @DoubleAA Indeed a “*maaseh Sedom*” but didn’t cause the deluge.

Comment: Couldn't it have? Was eating meat then less strict than the other 6 Mitzvot

Comment: Do you have a baseline for the Jewish traditional version?

Comment: @DoubleAA Maybe, maybe not, but eating it with ketchup I’d wager even Gordon Ramsey wouldn’t exterminate a whole generation; never mind the sources don’t seem to point to that “sin”.

Comment: @Alex The central passages in scripture (Gen. ch. 6 until wherever the film’s corresponding narrative ends) and Rabbinic (read: Oral Torah) elucidations/commentary.

Comment: Once you allow Rabbinic elucidations/commentary, you have a lot of different versions for the film to fit with.

Comment: @Alex True, and it’s not something I’d shun if their version fits with the interpretation of, say, Saadia Gaon.

Comment: Well from what I remember, a major plot point was that Noah decided that humanity had failed and should not continue, and tried to kill his grandchild(ren?). Does that fit any rabbinic elucidations/commentary?

Comment: It's probably nowhere near as entertaining as the Noah part of "The Green Pastures", a mid-30's all-black Bible movie.  There, "De Lawd" decides to wipe 'em out because of all the sinning - cheating at dice and cards, "speakin ill o' de' dead", knifing romantic rivals in zoot suits, etc.  Great, great movie-check it out  when it's on - angels with cardboard wings, all sorts of good stuff.

Comment: @Alex It can fit with the Rabbinic legend that [Noah did in fact preach repentance but it fell on deaf ears](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42359&st=&pgnum=25); perhaps at some later point, in tandem with the interpretation that [Noah didn’t pray on behalf of his generation](https://www.sefaria.org/Zohar.1.67b.3?with=all&lang=bi), he decided humanity failed. Re. the attempt at prolicide; I’m at a loss. Need more context.

Comment: @Oliver The point was that since he thought humanity had failed he decided that they should not repopulate the world. When one of the women became pregnant (with twins I think) he wanted to therefore kill the babies.

Comment: @Alex The idea that Noah reject propagation has basis in a [Midrash](https://www.sefaria.org/Midrash_Tanchuma_Buber%2C_Bereshit.39.1?with=all&lang=bi), though the notion of actual prolicide may indeed be unfounded and mere dramatization.

Comment: @Oliver That Midrash is talking about *before* the Deluge; the film is talking about *after* the deluge. And in the Midrash he eventually decided that פריה ורביה trumped his concern (though I think in the film he eventually gave in).

Comment: @Alex Oh, I should’ve realized that difference in your choice of word “*re*populate” (*after* the deluge). ITC, this example can be one answer. Thanks!

Comment: Well, some of the characters have the same names...

Comment: After reading the "plot" section of your link, it seems that a read of the Torah version shows there's an awful lot of differences between the movie and the "Jewish traditional" version.  Like basically all the subplots mentioned - the Tubal-Cain stuff, Shem's raft and children after the rain stuff...lots! But the description says "inspired by", so you can't really expect accuracy.  Probably about 100(maybe 110?) of the 125 million spent was on non-traditional scenes.  I still prefer "The Green Pastures", where Noah argues over how many kegs of liquor to pack "for medicinal purposes".